# Zend Framwork crashed when newrelic was enabled

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, newrelic, zend-server

I created a new ZF1 application (1.12.0) with zf tool like this:

`zf create project test`

I then enabled the layout as follow:

`zf enable layout`

And when I enabled newrelic I got this error:

```
PHP Error:
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Layout_Exception' with message 'Invalid method 'getmodulename' called on layout action helper' /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Action/Helper/Layout.php : 184
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What did you try? Show us some work.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: Well a good first step will be to Google the issue, then to go over a stack trace and so on.

Answer (score 6):

The way in which New Relic names Zend transactions is to hook into `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker::routeShutdown()` and look at various methods in the single argument that that function receives, which is the request. That parameter is supposed to be a class that has several methods: `getModuleName()`, `getControllerName()`, and `getActionName()`. The PHP agent expects to be able to call all of those functions on the request.

If you have highly customized your Zend framework installation, you may need to resort to naming your transaction manually. In this case, in your PHP INI file set `newrelic.framework = "none"` and at an appropriate place in your router, call `newrelic_name_transaction()`. You may be able to avoid this by determining why your request object does not have those standard functions.

One possible reason that this may occur is because you have an incomplete overloaded plugin router.

More information on this API call as well as others can be found in the New Relic KB:

https://newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php